# I have done something like this and it throws: UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'context' referenced before assignment error

Tags: python, django

After modifying the code:

```
class Index(FrontendMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = "myapp/frontend/index.html"
```

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    context = []

    if Post.objects.filter(deleted_at__isnull=True).count() > 1:
        context['Allpost'] = Post.objects.filter(publish=True).order_by('-created_at')
        context['mostrecentnews'] = News.objects.filter(publish=True, deleted_at__isnull=True).order_by('-created_at')[:1]
    else:
        context = []

    return {'context':context}
```

it throws TypeError `at list indices must be integers or slices, not str error.`

```
class Index(FrontendMixin,TemplateView):
    template_name = "myapp/frontend/index.html"
```

```
def get_context_data(self,**kwargs):
    super().get_context_data(**kwargs)

    if Post.objects.filter(deleted_at__isnull=True).count() > 1:
        context['Allpost'] = Post.objects.filter(publish=True).order_by('-created_at')
        context['mostrecentnews'] = News.objects.filter(publish=True, deleted_at__isnull=True).order_by('-created_at')[:1]
    else:
        context = []

    return {'context':context}
```

throws: **UnboundLocalError at / local variable 'context' referenced before assignment error**

Please advice to get rid of this error

Comment: in the second code block  `context` is out of scope

Comment: no, it's inside the scope but I forgot to assign the result of the super call. I got the answer now.

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to assign the result of the super call.

```
context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
```

And remove the other assignment to an empty list.